# Can people hack your iPhone Via Bluetooth if you leave it on?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

I live in an apartment complex with lots of people, and oftentimes I would be able to see Bluetooth devices that do not belong to me on my iPhone or MacBook when I search for my Bluetooth device.

Does Apple tell you/ask by default before someone with a Bluetooth device tries to connect to your phone via Bluetooth? Or is this a potential security vulnerability to leave your iPhone Bluetooth on at all times? (I do since I use AirPods)

I don’t remember setting or seeing any options to set Bluetooth permission on my iPhone, which makes me nervous.

Comment: Note that on the Android side of things, the sky is indeed falling with [BlueFrag](https://insinuator.net/2020/02/critical-bluetooth-vulnerability-in-android-cve-2020-0022/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it. Your iPhone cannot know which Bluetooth devices you own. Therefore it displays all devices it can see. That is perfectly normal. But there will only be a connection if you, personally, connect to that device. So your neighbour cannot connect his device to your phone without you knowingly doing it.

Comment: And if it were possible, it would be a major vulnerability.